# How to write unit tests when a private variable is used in all public functions?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, junit3

I have a function named `LoginInteractor.java` like this:

```
public class LoginInteractor {

    private LoginSessionManager loginSessionManager;
    private static LoginInteractor instance;

    public static LoginInteractor getInstance() {
        if (instance != null) {
            return instance;
        }
        instance = new LoginInteractor();
        return instance;
    }

    private LoginInteractor() {
        loginSessionManager = LoginSessionManager.getInstance();
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return loginSessionManager.isLoggedIn();
    }

    public Intent getLoginIntent() {
        return loginSessionManager.getLoginIntent();
    }
}
```

and another class `LoginSessionManager.java` like this:

```
public class LoginSessionManager {

    private LoginManager loginManager;
    private LogoutInterface logoutInterface;
    private static LoginSessionManager loginSessionManager;

    public static LoginSessionManager getInstance() {
        if (loginSessionManager != null) {
            return loginSessionManager;
        }
        loginSessionManager = new LoginSessionManager();
        return loginSessionManager;
    }

    private LoginSessionManager() {
        loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return LoginManager.getInstance().isLoggedIn();
    }

    public Intent getLoginIntent() {
        return loginManager.newLoginIntent();
    }

    public Intent getLogoutIntent() {
        return loginManager.newLogoutIntent();
    }
}
```

I'm writing unit tests for the class `LoginInteractor` in `LoginInteractorTest.kt` and this is how I have written unit tests for two functions.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PrepareForTest(
    UserInteractor::class,
    TextUtils::class,
    LoginInteractor::class,
    LoginSessionManager::class
)
class LoginInteractorTest : TestCase() {
    @Mock
    private lateinit var loginInteractor: LoginInteractor

    @Mock
    private lateinit var loginSessionManager: LoginSessionManager
    
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    public override fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)
        Whitebox.setInternalState(LoginSessionManager::class.java, "loginSessionManager", loginSessionManager)
        Whitebox.setInternalState(LoginInteractor::class.java, "instance", loginInteractor)
    }

    @Test
    fun isLoggedInTest(){
        `when`(loginSessionManager.isLoggedIn).thenReturn(true)
        assertEquals(true, loginInteractor.isLoggedIn)
    }

    @Test
    fun getLoginIntentTest(){
        `when`(loginSessionManager.loginIntent).thenReturn(Intent())
        assertNotNull(loginInteractor.loginIntent)
    }
}
```

Both of them are failing. For the first one, it says `expected is true, but actual is false` and for the second unit test, it says `AssertionError`

I suspect that the problem is when creating an instance of `LoginInteractor`, `loginSessionManager` variable is initialised in its private constructor. But when we say `WhiteBox(...LoginSessionManager...)`, this is a completely different object.

How to resolve this issue and make the unit tests run perfectly.

Comment: This won't solve your problem but you should switch `assertEquals` arguments. The first one is the *expected* value, the second one is the *actual* value, the one returned by the method under test. You did the opposite.

Comment: Edited. Now, about the actual problem

Comment: If you "suspect" something, your test isn't doing what it needs to. Write an additional test that runs first that lets you _verify_, or rule out, your suspicion. Even write some normal, non-test [mcve] code to test your hypothesis if you have to, then update your test(s) to account for what you learned. And change your class field visibility and see what happens: you'll be changing it back, but it lets you gain insight.

Comment: I'm very new to writing unit tests and not sure how and what many ways of writing them are there. I took another similar file as reference and wrote this. Have to see your suggestion.

Comment: If you suspect it's because the fields are private, make them public. You're not writing new code right now that's going to suddenly exploit those fields being public, you're just testing, so if you think that the fact that they're private is the problem: that will tell you whether that's true or not.

Comment: You are mocking the class you are testing. This can't work. You didn't define the behavior of `LoginInteractor.isLoggedIn` on the mock. When you test a class, you should mock its dependencies, not the class itself. If you do, how can you test the *actual* code of the tested class?

Comment: @thchp
Your suggestion has worked. I changed to LoginInteractor initialisation.
But only the first unit test is passing. If I write 5 unit tests, only first one is passing. If I remove the first one, and now we have 4, now, first one among them is passing. Rest all are failing

Comment: You should post another question with the new problem you encounter, or try to debug to see what is the variable values in each test, maybe you'll figure it yourslef